# Celery task testcase refuses to complete

Tags: django, unit-testing, rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery task that iterates through a django queryset. For each iteration, my code interacts with an external api. When i run my testcase to test the task, for some unknown reasons test doesn't complete

```py
# celery task

@shared_task
def iterate_and_compute():
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    for item in qs:
       iteract_with_external_api()
```

```py
# my testcase
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Product
from myapp.tasks import iterate_and_compute


class TaskTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # do some setup, like creating some products

    def test_iterate_and_compute_is_successful():
        task = iterate_and_compute.delay()
        res = task.get()
        self.assertEqual(task.status, 'SUCCESS')
```

celery worker is started like so:

`celery -A myproject worker -l INFO -P solo`

my test is run like so:

`python manage.py test myapp.tests.test_tasks.TaskTestCase.test_iterate_and_compute_is_successful`

From celery worker i get this response, that task succeeded

```
Task myapp.tasks.iterate_and_compute[71ab0ede-3a58-476b-a5cd-27e56552e9f1] succeeded in 0.07800000000861473s: None
```

This is the response i get from my test console

```
python manage.py test myapp.tests.test_tasks.TaskTestCase.test_iterate_and_compute_is_successful
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

That response remains like so for minutes.

## Do's & Dont's

- i'm not chaining / grouping task and no other task is called within `iterate_and_compute` task
- within my iterate_and_compute task i use `time.sleep(25)` which should only last for 25 seconds

## What i've tried

- I've tried starting my celery worker with different queues and call my task with apply_async and assign it to a queue
- I've tried ignoring task results `@shared_task(ignore_result=True)`
- Initially no `return` after the iteration in my iterate_and_compute task, i added `return` just to see if it'll make any difference.
- I've tried setting a soft_time_limit on my task, but because i'm running on a windows OS, soft_time_limit is not supported
- I've searched stack overflow to see if there's anything related (prob. i missed a solution) bt i didn't find any.

## Uses

- celery==4.4.7
- Django==3.1.1
- django-celery-results==1.2.1
- rabbitmq_server-3.8.5
- ErlangOTP-23.1.1

How can i make my testcase to completely run and show result of my test ?

Comment: Why not write a test for just `iterate_and_compute()`? You shouldn't need celery, a queue, workers, etc to run a unit test.

Comment: i get your point, but according to my research calling `iterate_and_compute()` doesn't actually mimic how celery task will  run on production as it wouldn't run as a background service. Doing that will only just test the logic.